# how to change date separator in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using date pipe to format date, and unable to change date separator,
I want to format date in following way "27.07.2016".
I have tried using following code

```
{{dateValue | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}
```

but above code formats date as "27/07/2016"

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that `dateValue` doesn't have **`Date type`**. You have to make sure that `dateValue` has **`Date type`**.

eg.

```
dateValue: Date = new Date();      // Date type. Make sure date is assgined to dateValue not string value.

{{dateValue | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}  // this will work.
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vjqFcUZqxrgGYYjAvy1g?p=preview

Comment: plunker is not loading, by the way dateValue has date type value, and I have tried using above same code but result is same it is formatting date in slash format

Comment: Plunker works fine. Check again. Show me how does `dateValue` get value in code

Comment: dateValue returns date in following format 
Wed Jul 27 2016 12:38:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),

plunker is showing errors on console, 403 and Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET